# ImportError: cannot import name ESUtil

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

Here below is the error which I am getting

```
(env) C:\Users\Prajna\Documents\FR-Python-master\python>python FR_Flask.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FR_Flask.py", line 26, in <module>
    import RemoveDuplicates as rd
  File "C:\Users\Prajna\Documents\FR-Python-master\python\RemoveDuplicates.py", line 19, in <module>
    from utils import ESUtil as elastic
ImportError: cannot import name ESUtil
```

And I am importing the below two lines in my code

```
from utils import ESUtil as elastic
from utils import FRUtils as frutils
```

How can I resolve this error? Do I need to install any packages other than using pip command?
I have used the below command to install utils

```
pip install utils
```

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the wrong package.

You installed and imported https://pypi.org/project/utils/ - see here what it provides: https://github.com/haaksmash/pyutils

Depending on what you really mean with esutil you might want to look through

- https://pypi.org/project/esutil/#description
- https://pypi.org/project/django-esutils/
- https://pypi.org/project/django-es-utils/

and

- https://pypi.org/project/fr-utils/ (currently not found?)